# Lightning Components Reserved Var Names

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Working with Lightning Components, I encountered the following problem. When I try to init some var within my controller method using the name of ***"arguments"*** my LC component stops loading.

```
onSearchButtonClick: function (component, event, helper) {
        let fromTimeValue = component.find('from-time').get('v.value');
        let toTimeValue = component.find('to-time').get('v.value');
        let arguments = {
            'fromTime': fromTimeValue,
            'toTime': toTimeValue
        };
        helper.loadDataWithParams(component, arguments, event);
}
```

However, when I change the name of this var to any other one it works. I suspect that the ***"arguments"*** keyword is reserved, but unfortunately, I couldn't get detailed information about the list of *reserved* words in the LC. Maybe someone can clarify this problem? Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, I have found out what was a problem.

[ES5 §15.1.1](https://es5.github.io/#x15.1.1)

Value Properties of the Global Object (`NaN`, `Infinity`, `undefined`), as well as strict mode restricted identifiers `eval` and `arguments` are considered to be **restricted names in JavaScript**. Defining them to mean something else can have unintended consequences and confuse others reading the code.

The full table of ***JavaScript Reserved Words*** is available below:

[JavaScript Reserved Words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about what the problem is exactly, since it seems that browsers let you override the native `arguments` object, but I'm guessing that a linter is raising a problem because doing so could cause bugs in the code.

To answer your question, these are the reserved keywords in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords

Here's a reference to the `arguments` object if you want more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments